# How to configure compilation output to a certain directory in android studio

Tags: android-studio, backendless

I am using using Backendless as mbaas. Currently working on custom business logic. But am stuck, in their documentation they've stated "...configure compilation output to [directory]. I can figure it out how to do this in android studio. 
I would gladly appreciate any help.

Comment: Just install IntelliJ and keep your server project separate to your app

Comment: Thank you you Wain. I have installed intellij idea and configured output directory of modules. But when i compile that module, there is still nothing in that output directory is specified. What am i not doing?

Comment: You'd need to explain what you did to configure it

Comment: I solved the issue. Thanks Wain